# Problem with this error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Tags: java, string

This is the problem wherein, we will subtract two numbers using 9's complement.

```
import java.io.*;

   public class NinesComplement {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws java.io.IOException {
        java.io.BufferedReader br = new java.io.BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(System.in));
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter Minuend: ");
            int min = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            System.out.print("Enter Subtrahend: ");
            String sub = br.readLine();

            int max = Integer.toString(min).length();
            for (int i = 0; sub.length() < max; i++) {
                sub = 0 + sub;
            }

            String [] subArr = sub.split("");
            int[] num = new int[subArr.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < subArr.length; i++) {
                num[i] = Integer.parseInt(subArr[i]);
            }

            int[] n = new int[num.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
                for (int ii = 0; num[i] < 9; ii++) {
                    num[i]++;
                    n[i]++;
                }
            }

            String str = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < num.length; i++) {
                str += Integer.parseInt(Integer.toString(n[i]));
            }

            int add = Integer.parseInt(str);
            String ans = Integer.toString(min + add);

            if (ans.length() > max) {
                String temp1 = ans.substring(0, 1);
                String temp2 = ans.substring(1, ans.length());
                int fin = Integer.parseInt(temp2) + Integer.parseInt(temp1);
                System.out.println("Answer: " + fin);
            } else if (ans.startsWith("9") && ans.endsWith("9")) {
                System.out.println("Answer: 0");
            }

            System.out.print("Do you want to try again? \n[y][n]: ");
            String choice = br.readLine();
            if (choice.equals("n")) {
                System.out.println("Thank you!!!");
                        System.exit(0);
    }
    }
    }
}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: ""

Comment: The error message means that you are trying to parse an empty string as if it is a number. An empty string does not contain a number, so you get this exception. Pay close attention to the complete error message, it tells you exactly in which line of your code the exception occurs.

Comment: Fix your code so that it will not parse an empty string as if it contains a number.

Comment: The problem is, I just copied this code to somebody. Hahaha

Answer (score 0):

You're just trying to parse an empty string into a number.  **You should always validate user input before trying to use it :).**

Add a pre-condition (just an if statement check) before using the input and print a nice message to the user if the input was bad, and just go back to waiting for more good input.

Also, to debug this issue, just make your life easier and add some print statements surrounded by quotes before you try and use the user input so you can see it.